# cannot write Active Directory Shares mounted with pam_mount

Tags: mount, permissions, samba, active-directory

I am using centrifydc to connect an Ubuntu 13.10 desktop to our Active Directory. Login to the Ubuntu computer using the AD Credentials are working fine. I am using pam_mount to mount a share located in a Windows 2008 R2 server everytime an AD domain user logs onto the Ubuntu computer. The volumen definition in `pam_mount.conf.xml` file is as follows:

```
volume user="my_user" fstype="cifs" server="my_server" path="UsersFolders/%(USER)/Documents"  
    mountpoint="~/UserDocuments" options="file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,sec=ntlm"
```

When I log on to Ubuntu I can see that the share is mounted, I can access and open the files already stored in the share but I cannot perform any change to them. Save button is grayed in LibreOffice. If I open a file with LibreOffice, I can use the option SaveAs with a different name and the file is saved correctly but when I open it again the save button is grayed

Am I missing something? Could this be a problem with the way the shares are mounted or with LibreOffice.

Answer (score 0):

every thing it's OK but u should add these option with your options code

```
uid=941100071
```

to be

```
olume user="my_user" fstype="cifs" server="my_server" path="UsersFolders/%(USER)/Documents"  
mountpoint="~/UserDocuments" options="file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,sec=ntlm,uid=941100071"
```

i was have the same problem with fstab and the uid was a solution .

---

i advice u to try these

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

after code post this

```
//10.0.0.0/path /home/path cifs username=ADusername,password=ADpass,uid=941100071 0 0
```